# C# Performance setting value for each list item

Tags: c#, performance, search, list

I am trying to find the fasted way to set a specific property of every item in a generic list.

Basicly the requirement is to iterate over a list of items and resetting the IsHit property to FALSE. Only the items in a second "hit"-list should be set to TRUE afterwards.

My first attempt looked like this:

```
listItems.ForEach(delegate(Item i) { i.IsHit = false; });

foreach (int hitIndex in hits)
{
    listItems[hitIndex - 1].IsHit = true;
}
```

Note: hits is 1-based, the items list is 0-based.

Then i tried to improve the speed and came up with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listItems.Count; i++)
{
    bool hit = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < hits.Count; j++)
    {
        if (i == hits[j] - 1)
        {
            hit = true;
            hits.RemoveAt(j);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (hit)
    {
        this.listItems[i].IsHit = true;
    }
    else
    {
        this.listItems[i].IsHit = false;
    }
}
```

I know this is a micro optimization but it is really time sensitive code, so it would make sense to improve this code beyond readibility... and just for fun of course ;-)

Unfortuanetly I don't really see any way to improve the code further. But I probably missed something.

Thanks

PS: Code in C# / .NET 2.0 would be preferred.

---

I ended up switching to Eamon Nerbonne solution. But then I noticed something weird in my benchmarks.

The delegate:

```
listItems.ForEach(delegate(Item i) { i.IsHit = false; });
```

is faster than:

```
foreach (Item i in listItems)
{
    i.IsHit = false;
}
```

How is that possible?

I tried to look at IL but thats just way over my head... I only see that the delegates results in fewer lines, whatever that means.

Comment: any chance to change the "hit"-list to a hashtable? Would improve performance drastically by removing the second for-loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nested for-loop is overkill, and in particular, the "remove" call itself represents yet another for-loop.  All in all, your second optimized version has a worse time-complexity than the first solution, in particular when there are many hits.

The fastest solution is likely to be the following:

```
foreach(var item in listItems)
    item.IsHit = false;
foreach (int hitIndex in hits)
    listItems[hitIndex - 1].IsHit = true;
```

This avoids the inefficient nested for-loops, and it avoids the overhead of the delegate based `.ForEach` method (which is a fine method, but not in performance critical code).  It involves setting IsHit slightly more frequently, but most property setters are trivial and thus this is probably not a bottleneck.  A quick micro-benchmark serves as a fine sanity check in any case.

**Only if `IsHit` is truly slow**, the following will be quicker:

```
bool[] isHit = new bool[listItems.Count]; //default:false.
//BitArray isHit = new BitArray(listItems.Count);  
//BitArray is potentially faster for very large lists.
foreach (int hitIndex in hits)
    isHit [hitIndex - 1] = true;
for(int i=0; i < listItems.Count; i++)
    listItems[i].IsHit = isHit[i];
```

Finally, consider using an array rather than a `List<>`.  Arrays are generally faster if you can avoid needing the `List<>` type's insertion/removal methods.

The `var` keyword is C# 3.5 but can be used in .NET 2.0 (new language features don't require newer library versions, in general - it's just that they're most useful with those newer libs).  Of course, you know the type with which `List<>` is specialized, and can explicitly specify it.

Comment: Minor note on the complexity of the OP's second version: the Remove call will iterate precisely over those elements of hits *not* iterated over by the explicit inner for loop, so the overal complexity of that solution is on the order of `listItems.Count` × `hits.Count`

Answer (score 3):

Can you put the items of your second list in a dictionary ?
If so, you can do this:

```
for( int i = 0; i < firstList.Count; i++ )
{
   firstList[i].IsHit = false;

   if( secondList.Contains (firstList[i].Id) )
   {
       secondList.Remove (firstList[i].Id);
       firstList[i].IsHit = true;
   }
}
```

Where secondList is a Dictionary offcourse.

By putting the items of your histlist in a Dictionary, you can check with an O(1) operation if an item is contained in that list.
In the code above, I use some kind of unique identifier of an Item as the Key in the dictionary.

Comment: Instead of dictionary you could use HashSet<T>. Also, there is no need to remove hits from the dictionary/set if you are sure that all hits will be "used" - just empty the collection after the loop.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the HashSet collection.  I sometimes forget about its existence though :o.
About removing items from the set or dictionary: I've just done it because I saw the topicstarter was doing it as well in his example code.  Maybe he has another reason for it, but it is indeed not necessary to do this when using a set or dictionary performancewise.

Comment: `HashSet<>` and `Dictionary<>` are a lot slower than plain old array's - and since you're dealing with dense integer indexes, hashsets and dictionaries have no meaningful additional functionality here.

Comment: Well, seems like there are no reputation points in courtesy...at least an upvote on the comment would have been nice.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe sort the hits collection and perform a binary search, then you would be O(n log<sub>2</sub> n) instead of O(n<sup>2</sup>)